# What are the halachot of identity theft or misrepresentation online?

Tags: halacha, names, internet, emes-truth-honesty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [False portrayal on an anonymous Q&A site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/false-portrayal-on-an-anonymous-qa-site)

Is using a misleading name or avatar online halachically permissible?

Comment: definitely a duplicate

Comment: with your permission then....

Comment: :) 13 more to go...

Comment: Hmmm... someone has a guilty conscience? :)

Comment: 13 more what?...

Comment: @Dave the question wasn't posted seriously, just to mess with you. @ Hod - characters left before it would let me post that comment.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave likewise. (hence the smiley)