# Do traditional sources address how time “works”?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, time, science

I’m sorry for such a convoluted question, but this has been bothering me for some time now. While the title isn’t quite accurate, I couldn’t think of a better way to phrase it - feel free to edit if you can.

In sci-fi literature, (backwards) time travel tends to take one of two forms: either (1) one’s actions were already taken into account in the timeline, leading to the trope of someone trying to prevent something from happening but causes it to happen in the end (think *Doctor Who*); or (2) one can actually alter the past, leading to a branching timeline (think *Back to the Future*).

Does Judaism address whether either of these are accurate? That is, [assuming time travel is possible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8496/), can one go back in time and alter the past?

The flip side of the coin, which might open some other possibilities for answers: if I somehow receive a message from the future, can I take measures to prevent it from happening, or will it automatically happen regardless of what I do?

---

The main question ends here. The following are some of my thoughts on potential proofs one way or another from methods we know to be true of predicting the future.

While astrology, kishuf, necromancy, and urim v’tumim all do this to some effect or another, there is a fundamental issue with all of them that prevents them from being proofs - namely, a large portion of the message is left up to interpretation, and thus any inaccuracies might be chalked up to user error. Take the example of Paroh’s message of Ra’ah (Shemos 10:10) - while one could argue that the symbol was overturned, one could just as easily argue that it was never intended to refer to murder, and Paroh misread the stars.

Nevuah, also, isn’t a good proof: a negative prophecy can be overturned, but perhaps it was just to scare the people and never was intended to be fulfilled at all. A positive prophecy might never be overturned, but that could be just because Hashem doesn’t lie - not that it fundamentally *can’t* be overturned, but that He *chooses* not to overturn it.

While different, [yedi’ah versus bechirah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/856/9682) is very heavily related.

Comment: So you're not interested in self fulfilling prophecies?

Comment: @robev If you could bring a proof from one I’d be interested, but only if it can avoid the issues I raised in the question.

Comment: Basically, since we cannot prove one way or the other, it is not worth asking. All we can know is the way things actually happen. There is no way we can actually prove either way.

Comment: Ibn Ezra holds that what is written in the stars will come to be, and someone who is connected to spirituality can use that to his advantage, or if G-d decides to save him he will do it by making sure he is somewhere else when the foretold event happens. -- http://olvreader.sefereshet.org.il/Olive/OTB/OpenU/?href=C10412/2008/01/02&usticket=Z3Vlc3Q&ticket= -- section 5.9.5 of this book, and especially 5.9.5.3

Comment: @Menachem That could be an answer.

Comment: what is written in the stars in present, not future, it means that future events already exist in the stars... (so i believe)

Comment: One argument in favor of your option (1) is that one is not allowed to pray to change something in the past, (though I suppose if you do enough handwaving you make option (2)  fit as well).

Comment: "Fodder" - There is a debate as to whether the Torah is written chronologically, or not. I think Ramba"m feels that it is, generally. So, think about the ending of *parshat hamahn* that says that B'nei Yisra'el ate the mahn for 40 years in the desert. Was that statement edited in later, or was it prophecy or something that predicted a future event?

Comment: @DanF Probably edited in later. Cf. Gid HaNasheh according to the Chachamim.

Comment: This seems to be the classic debate of bechira vs. Hashem’s control. Is everything already set by Hashem or do we actually make decisions that can alter what was planned. I believe there are varying opinions on this but I don’t know them so well.

Comment: @JediPythonClone The question isn’t bechirah vs. control, but rather bechirah vs. yedi’a - Hashem knows what I’ll choose, so is that really considered choice? Hashem allows us free will - or else there’s no purpose to our existence. There is no Jewish scholar who can say that free will doesn’t exist.

Comment: @DonielF while I do agree with you I believe in this question both are relevant. I chose to mention control because once you are dealing with time travel, Hashem will know what will happen in each “branch” of time. Therefore the concept of yediah is less relevant.

Comment: @JediPythonClone Once again, I don’t think control is at all an issue. Besides, this entire discussion is assuming that time travel is possible in the first place.

Comment: @DonielF control would be relevant because if Hashem is controlling what happens, He presumably won’t change His “mind” and the same events would play out no matter what you do.....the reason yediah is irrelevant is based on the premise of time travel existing as I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: @JediPythonClone I agree that yediah doesn’t make a difference - that’s entirely my point. As for control, isn’t that the entire point of bechirah? That *you* get to decide how history plays out? While, as we see from Megillas Esther, the ultimate conclusion will be the same regardless, it’s up to you *how* it plays out. And maybe your going back in time to change things is necessary for that conclusion to occur. Since we can’t read G-d’s mind, there’s no way for us to know what that conclusion is until it happens.

Comment: @DonielF I realize now that I was very ambiguous before. By control I meant Hashem’s control over what happens

Comment: That's a tautology: if time travel is going back in time and interact with the environment, *"assuming time travel is possible, can one go back in time and alter the past?"*. The answer is "assuming it is possible - it is possible."

Comment: Based on the body of the question, please fix the title "Do traditional sources address how time “works” which does not reflect it. Something about time travel, please.

Comment: @AlBerko It’s not quite about time travel, as it would equally apply if you take time travel out of the equation. It’s just much easier (to me, anyway) to hear the two sides when you discuss it in terms of time travel - can the past be changed? - though you could ask the same question as “is the future fixed”? (Hence my reference to Yedi’a and Bechirah.)

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into comparing sci-fi literature to lehavdil Judaism. Time holds a prominent place in Judaism.

It is the thing that, in a sense, dominates a Jews life. It decided when one must recite a prayer (Krias Shema), it directs man to abstain from labor (Shabbos), and it demands when one must preform other ritual duties (Korban Pesach, Korban Bein Ha’arbayim, etc.)

Yet we also find that man (more specifically the Rabbis), in a sense, have a mastery over time. For example, the Mitzvah to Sanctify the New Moon, known as Kiddush Hachodesh. Two witnesses are brought in, and through their testimony of the seeing the new moon, the Beis Din declares the new month, which then sets off a myriad of obligations.

There is a fascinating Midrash in the Yakut Shimoni that attests to this idea, that Man plays a powerful part, almost on par with G-d himself, in the control of time:

> מתכנסים מלאכי השרת אצל הקב"ה ואומרים לפניו: "רבונו של עולם, אימתי ראש
> השנה?" והוא אומר: "ולי אתם שואלים? אני ואתם נשאל לבית דין של מטה!"
>
> גזרו בית דין של מטה ואמרו "היום ראש השנה", אומר הקב"ה למלאכים: "העמידו
> בימה, והעמידו סנגורים והעמידו ספיקטורים [מקטרגים], מפני שגזרו בית דין
> של מטה ואמרו היום ראש השנה!". נשתהו העדים לבוא, או נמלכו בית דין לעברה
> למחר [החליטו לדחות את קידוש החודש למחר] - הקב"ה אומר למלאכי השרת:
> "העבירו בימה, ויעבירו סנגורים ויעבירו ספיקטורים, שגזרו בית דין של מטה
> ואמרו, ראש השנה למחר". (ילקוט שמעוני בא קצ, קצא
>
> The angels gathered together with the Holy One, blessed be He, and
> said to Him: "Master of the world, when is the New Year?" G-d
> responded : " Why do you ask me? Rather, let us ask the Lower Court
> (the Human Court)
>
> The Beis Din declared: "Today is Rosh Hashanah,"
>
> G-d said to the angels: "Put up a stage, and put up defense attorneys,
> and set up accusers, because they decreed a court of heaven and said
> today Rosh Hashana!"
>
> However, the witnesses failed to come, or the Beis Din decided to push
> Rosh Hashana off till tomorrow.
>
> The Almighty said to the ministering angels: "remove the stage, remove
> defenders and Remove spikers, for the Court has ruled that Rosh
> Hashana is tomorrow."

We see that time, and the obligations that stem from it are placed in the hands of man, and thus make it, in a sense malleable. For how can time, being that Rosh Hashana is the literal date and beginning of the world (yes, this aspect is subject to a tannaic dispute, but the point nonetheless stands), be subject to the decisions of the Beis Din. There are further examples of this that we find throughout halacha (the status of a girl physical maturity etc. the bringing of the Korban Ha’omer).

These are but a few examples, but i hope to add more.

Regarding time travel in general, we find the Gemara in Taanis (23a)

Comment: While the last bit about *that* time travel is possible doesn’t exactly address the question - that’s better suited for the question I linked in the OP. The first bit absolutely addresses it, and I’ll have to think about that a bit.

Comment: @DonielF duly noted. I'll take it out till I flesh it out more. Because it does answer your question.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to the idea of Time? We're free to set our milestones, but how does that change the time?

Comment: @AlBerko the fact that we can set dates and markers, and thus moving the day that we commemorate the day of creation, it is as if we have power over time itself

Comment: If I celebrate my birthdays - what power over my birth do I have? Rosh Chodesh has nothing to do with the passing of time - whether we Mekadshim or not - it passes, the Moon does not stop and waits.

Comment: Also Rosh Chodesh has no influence at all as the Gemmorah itself brings opinions that Rosh Chodesh needs no Kidush as it happens all by itself. R' Yehoshua wanted Yom Kippur on one day and Rabban Gamliel on another - so what did it change?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to write my comments as an answer, but it might help to think of some additional ideas.

When watching a movie on a PC I asked myself: "How come, the whole movie is stored on my disc as a file, but I can only watch it sequentially?"

Same with the creation, it is one "4D" piece that unfolds before our eyes sequentially. I met this concept a lot in the Lurianic (Kabbalic) tradition (by R' Moshe Luria Z"L), for example:

1. תהו ובהו וחושך וכו - hints on the 4 Galuyot from the moment of the Creation
2. Abraham chased the enemies to Dan and then he suddenly weakened as his descendants are destined to sin at Dan
3. Binyomin wept at Yossef's neck upon the destruction of the two Temples, that Ariz"l says was destined and fixed in the creation.

In this approach, the time travel is impossible and meaningless as the Creation together with its timeline is one.

Therefore the question of "הכל צפוי והרשות נתונה" is resolved on the spiritual level only - the only thing a person is given powers to control is his "intentions" not deeds ("חוץ מיראת שמים"). This is unsourced, but that's what I learned from R' Luriah.

Comment: I already said that I’m basing my question on the premise that time travel is possible. Therefore this isn’t an answer - the Arizal learns like the other side in the debate, while I’m following those who say it is possible for the sake of this question.

Comment: You asked a very unclear question as the title does not correlate with your main question and the last paragraph is also off the time travel. You might want to focus on a specific point. I answered the title and the last paragraph.

Comment: Between your comment here and to my question it’s clear that you didn’t read it thoroughly enough. Assuming that time travel is possible, theoretically it would lead to one of two results: actually changing the timeline, or history already reflects your actions in the past. It’s not a tautology at all, and your answer is saying that a premise is false when, in fact, there seems to be enough Talmudic literature to support either side of the argument.

Comment: @DonielF "*or history already reflects your actions in the past*" - where did this come from? Can you give an example of it?

Comment: Second paragraph in my question. It’s exactly what it sounds like - you tripped over a rock, so you went back to move it out of the way so you wouldn’t trip over it, but instead ended up putting it in exactly the position where you tripped over it.

Comment: @DonielF I understand your problem with Doctor Who, it is not what you think, the main motif looks like the history repeats itself, but you overlook myriads of other interactions that would not be the same. So even if you tripped over a rock, the rest of the scene is not the same, which is contradictory to the first scenario. Hey, that's what Holywood is for! (I know it's BBC :(

Comment: I was using that as an example that reflects what I’m trying to describe. That theory is well supported by quantum physicists.

Comment: "Nothing theoretically contradicts" is far from "supports"... I'd say.

Comment: Did you mean to write that on the other thread?

Comment: Ok, I'm with you, time travel exists! So you sin, and instead of doing Teshuvah you go back and ...? Put it in Torah framework.please

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82276/discussion-between-donielf-and-al-berko).