# Why does shabbat start at different times at different places?

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, evening-night, kabbalat-shabbat

Crossing a time zone does not conjure up a time warp, so how can it be Friday in one place, and Shabbat in another?  It just doesn't seem possible.

Comment: If this question gets reopened, it should be rolled back to revision 1 based on https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5025/

Comment: This question was edited after answers responding to the original version were posted and, as far as I can tell, upvoted.  I have rolled back to a version that does not invalidate those answers.

Answer (score 7):

[Shabbat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat) starts no later than sunset (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 293:2).

[Sunset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunset) is a subjective phenomenon describing the apparent descent of the Sun below the horizon. It happens because the Earth is [round](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth#Shape) and [rotates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation) about its own axis much more quickly than it [revolves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit) around the Sun, so observers on its surface observe, once per rotation, their part of the Earth rotating away from the Sun to the point that the rest of the Earth blocks them from seeing the Sun. That point is sunset.

Because the timing of this phenomenon depends on the observer's location on the Earth, so does the timing of the latest time to start Shabbat. This timing varies [continuously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) with the observer's location on Earth, meaning that two people who are almost in the same place will observe almost the same time for sunset and would therefore be subject to almost the same limit for starting Shabbat, so there's no discontinuous "time warp" except at the [Halachic International Date Line](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues) (wherever that is).

Comment: 293:2? [15chara]

Answer (score 6):

It's because the world is Round!

*After I posted this **correct** anwer, the OP decided to change his question*

Comment: There are, of course [other](https://www.facebook.com/FlatEarthToday/) ['explanations'](http://timecube.2enp.com/)