# Mir Yeshiva and the Dateline

Tags: history, zemanim, mir

For a short while, the Mir Yeshiva was relocated to Kobe Japan at the outbreak of the Second World War. Since Japan is in question with the [International Dateline](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38494/2699) how did the Rosh Yeshiva Pasken for the Yeshiva? Whose opinion did they hold by regarding the dateline?

Comment: http://www.theus.org.uk/sites/default/files/BALAK%20Vol.26%20No.41.pdf

Comment: Partially covered here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues/38494#38494

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure my zeida told me they kept two days (of Yom Kippur) due to the safek, but on the second day they would eat less then the shiur, spaced apart, because at that point it was a question of pikuach neffesh due to the heat.