# Holidays south of the equator

Tags: halacha, history, geography, chagim-holidays

When Jews first started establishing communities south of the equator, they must have noticed that the holidays fell completely at the wrong times of the year. (For example, Pesach, referred to as hag ha-aviv, would be in the fall in the southern hemisphere). While they obviously kept the holidays where they are now, I feel that there must have been some discussion of this fact. Anyone know of anything?

Update/Clarification: I know there are many possible answers to the puzzle of what Jews should so in the southern hemisphere. I'm interested in the reasoning of rabbinic authorities at the times when these communities were first established. Especially if you have sources I can read.

Comment: Pesach didn't fall in the spring in northern Russia either. There was still snow on the ground!

Comment: The Jews of Australia also had to decide what day shabbat is on.

Comment: @Jake, that's a [different issue](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues).

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, I thought of that, but as long as you're staying in the northern hemisphere everything is only off by matters of degree. This causes serious halachic issues around the issues of Hadash/Yoshon, but that's another story. Once you cross the equator it's not a matter of degree anymore, but a complete inversion. While certainly someone could have used an argument from the "Pesach in winter in Russia" case when Jewish communities were set up in SA, I'm curious if they actually did.

Comment: @Bachrach44 I don't know what the difference is. The point is the weather doesn't matter except in Israel.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a difference of degree vs a difference in kind. My question isn't whether you can find a logical explanation for the current practice, my question was if anyone know of any primary sources that addressed this issue. In other words, I'm not interested in your logic, (nothing personal), I'm interested in the logic of the Jews at the times when these communities were established.

Comment: @Bachrach44 I know. I'm suggesting that no one would bother writing about it because no one would think the seasons in Australia matter.