# How can Australia celebrate Pesach at the same time of year as other countries?

Tags: passover, calendar, geography

The Torah commands that we celebrate Pesach in the spring time so how can Australia celebrate Pesach at the same time of year as other countries?

While I suspect the answer is that they celebrate at the time it is spring in Israel how does this fulfill the idea of celebrating during the spring time if in fact for a person living in Australia it isn't spring time?

Comment: Please edit in sources for your claims

Comment: Note the Jews left Egypt in March/April independent of the weather.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11508/759

Comment: A good question, Argentina also. I think that when we know that the whole people should celebrate the pessach, the majority &/or the emplacement of choice are the essential regarding the season, the climatic problems in Australia and other minoritary &/ not emplacement of choice are contingent. A kind of Zil batar ruba. But the days and nights remain essential in all cases. This is only svarot. I am very interesting to see how people would develop the topic

Comment: @DoubleAA Duplicate of [unanswered] http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45208/holidays-south-of-the-equator

Comment: The 2nd par. of your question, I believe, is the answer. The Torah was concerned with the Spring Equinox in Israel. More specifically, it was concerned with the ripening of the barley - again, as it ripens in Israel. It had no concern at all with what happens anywhere else - not Europe or U.S., or anywhere else in the North Hemisphere, and certainly, no concern about the Southern Hemisphere, either.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question you point to states specifically that he wants discussions from the time the communities were being established, not just the reasoning. This question wants the general reasoning.

Comment: @sabbahillel, sorry, you're quite right. I apologize and shall reopen.

Comment: i think the general answer is that which others have said, which is that the torah was only concerned with people being in Israel. However, i would imagine that if technology had not improved, and Jews ended up in Australia for a prolonged period of time, they would have celebrated in their spring time in order to be able to have fresh barley/wheat to grind and make matzah

Answer (score 4):

We have learned that whenever the Torah deals with relative times, the time expressed in the Torah is that of Eretz Yisrael. For example, the molad announced is Yerushalaim Solar Time (not even Israeli clock time which is 20 minutes later). Similarly, there is a commentary when Moshe Rabbeinu said "about midnight" he was speaking of Midnight Yerushalaim time rather than midnight in Egypt.

[Kehillas Yitzchak](http://ohr.edu/qa/5759/shmos/bo.htm) says:

> Hashem's 'clock' is set to Jerusalem. The plague of the first-born
>   took place at exactly midnight, Jerusalem time. But because Egypt is
>   west of Jerusalem, midnight there occurs later. When Moshe said the
>   plague would be at 'approximately midnight,' he was referring to
>   local, Egyptian time.
>
> (Kehillas Yitzchak; thanks to Rabbi Sholem Fishbane)

See [When is “vesain tal umotor” said in Australia?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/when-is-vesain-tal-umotor-said-in-australia/11509#11509) which shows how seasonal changes follow Eretz Yisrael.

Similarly, since leap year is based on Aviv in Eretz Yisrael, this shows that Australia would also have leap year based on the same calender and the circumstances in Eretz Yisrael.