# Six month daytime duration

Tags: time, geography, creation, sunset-shekia, hanetz-sunrise

In the Beresheit account of Creation, a day begins at sundown and ends the next day at sundown. But we know closer to each of the Earth's poles, an actual day can last up to six months. The sun rises and/or sets in six month intervals. How do we reconcile this with the apparent 24-hour day in the Creation narrative?

Comment: It is not at all clear the "days" in the account of Creation were 24-hour periods, if only because the sun and the moon weren't created until the fourth day. In any case welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

We probably look at it as 24 hours in Jerusalem (not on the poles)

See [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38494/5120) regarding the date line

Answer (score -3):

I would imagine that you would use the Moon as Gen 1:14-19 says. Days are defined by both Sun and Moon as above verses say, precisely for cases like this.

Comment: At the poles the moon stays up for 15 days at a time

Comment: @DoubleAA The shade does not ;)