# Israeli travelling in chutz la'aretz on second day Yom Tov (Hawaii)

Tags: chutz-laaretz

Is an Israeli allowed to leave Israel motzei chag and arrive in America on what is second day chag in America?

The flight would have a stopover in LAX (which I've read isn't an issue), but arriving in Honolulu and leaving the airport on second day chag may be an issue. The question seems to boil down to whether Honolulu is a yishuv with Jews. Seeing as almost no Jews live in Honolulu, is one permitted to leave the airport that day?

Comment: There are definitely Jews in Honolulu. Why do they need to be a majority to have a local Minhag? If he made Honolulu a stopover on the way to the Big Island then you might have something to talk about.

Comment: IF there is a problem at all, then it seems that the problem occurs already while in flight. Technically, once the plane is in the air, he has left Israel and is now "chutz la'aretz". Which begs the question if one is allowed to make such a flight in the first place.

Comment: @DanF No, the issue is only when you reach a settlement. There is no local custom in the air as it's uninhabited.

Comment: Yes Dan. That is a question, but I already have the answer for that and it's fine

Comment: There are enough Jews in Honolulu to have a daily _shacharis_ minyan: http://m.chabadofhawaii.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/115473

Comment: Does this question assume a particular stance on the dateline issue?

Comment: @LiquidMetal I'm not sure why this would be a factor. In any case, the halachic dateline is not the same as the International Date Line.

Comment: @DanF It could matter because he might be landing in Hawaii on first day Yom Tov, or on the day after second day Yom Tov, even if he left Israel on the second day. Also, the halachic dateline might be the same as the IDL.

Comment: @DoubleAA"Also, the halachic dateline might be the same as the IDL" - You may want to read Appendix II of Art Scroll Talmud Rosh Hashanna. That's not how it' s explained, there.

Comment: @DanF It wouldn't be the first time Artscroll left out opinions it doesn't like for whatever reason.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38494/6716 - related.  If IDL is it, it's based on R' Tzvi Pesach Frank's opinion that you go based on the community's accepted standard.

Comment: "The question seems to boil down to whether Honolulu is a yishuv with Jews." - Do you have a source for this?  What is the underlying problem?  מרעית עין?

Comment: A bunch of different sources online, but here's one: http://dinonline.org/2011/01/17/yom-tov-sheini-for-israelis-in-chuts-laaretz/